# Excel XLSM File issue

Tags: excel

I have created a Macro enabled workbook with a single worksheet for collecting specific data. The VBA project is password protected and also the worksheet is password protected. Size of the file is about 3 Mb.

Now the data is collected from about 20 team members. I am preparing a summary sheet and trying to get all the individual sheets into one workbook.

Move or copy workbook is causing Excel to hang.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Here is the code in the workbook:

```
Sub Open_SA()
' Open_SA Macro
' Open Appraisal Form for Self Appraisal
'Get Password
Dim MyPassword As String
MyPassword = "********"
If InputBox("You are not authorized. Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> MyPassword Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

'Unlock Sheet
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="********"

'Lock and hide all cells
Cells.Select
Selection.Locked = True
Selection.FormulaHidden = True

'Select SA related cells and Unlock
Range("C6:Z14,C17:Z25,C28:Z36,C39:Z47,W55:X60,W64:X75,W79:X81,A87:H87").Select

Selection.Locked = False
Selection.FormulaHidden = False

'Select L1 related cells and change the font color to background color
Range( _
    "AB7:AD9,AB18:AD20,AB29:AD31,AB40:AD42,Z55:AA60,Z64:AA75,Z79:AA81,L87:S87"). _
    Select

With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
End With


'Select L2 related cells and change the font color to background color
Range( _
    "AB12:AD14,AB23:AD25,AB34:AD36,AB45:AD47,AC55:AD60,AC64:AD75,AC79:AD81,W87:AD87"). _
    Select

With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
End With

'Hide Evaluation Cells
Range("AF85:AM93").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'Activate specific cell range
Range("C6:Z6").Select

'Lock Sheet
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="********", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    True

'Save workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

This is one of the modules. There are similar 4 modules.

Another module:

```
Sub Open_L1()
' Open_L1 Macro
' Open Appraisal Form for L1 Rating
'Get Password
Dim MyPassword As String
MyPassword = "********"
If InputBox("You are not authorized. Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> MyPassword Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

'Unlock Sheet
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="********"

'Lock and hide all cells
Cells.Select
Selection.Locked = True
Selection.FormulaHidden = True

'Select L1 related cells, Unlock cells and Set font color to automatic
Range( _
    "AB7:AD9,AB18:AD20,AB29:AD31,AB40:AD42,Z55:AA60,Z64:AA75,Z79:AA81,L87:S87"). _
    Select

Selection.Locked = False
Selection.FormulaHidden = True

With Selection.Font
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'Select L2 related cells and change the font color to background color
Range( _
    "AB12:AD14,AB23:AD25,AB34:AD36,AB45:AD47,AC55:AD60,AC64:AD75,AC79:AD81,W87:AD87"). _
    Select
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
End With

'Hide Evaluation Cells
Range("AF85:AM93").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'Activate specific cell range
Range("AB7:AD9").Select

'Lock Sheet
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="********", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False

'Save workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

This is step 2.

Other modules also do the same.

The general structure is:
 1. Get Password
 2. Unlock the sheet
 3. Select specific range of cells and perform an action like Make them visible, Change Font color or Make them hidden
 4. Lock the Sheet
 5. Save the workbook.

Comment: You need to share the code that is generating a problem

Comment: ok. I will add the code.

Comment: Which line and in which module is causing the code to hang?

Comment: Code is working fine. When I try to copy the sheet to a new workbook excel is hanging. I have tried on alternative PCs as well.